# Starting a python script from another before it crashes

Tags: python, restart

I'm trying to make some project code I have written, more resilient to crashes, except the circumstances of my previous crashes have all been different.
So that I do not have to try and account for every single one, I thought I'd try to get my code to either restart, or execute a copy of itself in place of it and then close itself down gracefully, meaning its replacement, because it's coded identically, would in essence be the same as restarting from the beginning again.  The desired result for me would be that while the error resulting circumstances are present, my code would be in a program swap out, or restart loop until such time as it can execute its code normally again....until the next time it faces a similar situation.

To experiment with, I've written two programs.  I'm hoping from these examples someone will understand what I am trying to achieve.  I want the first script to execute, then start the execute process for the second (in a new terminal) before closing itself down gracefully.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

first.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/bin/bash
#first.py

import time
import os
import sys
from subprocess import run
import subprocess

thisfile = "first"
#thisfile = "second"

time.sleep(3)
while thisfile == "second":
    print("this is the second file")
    time.sleep(1)
    #os.system("first.py")
    #exec(open("first.py").read())
    #run("python "+"first.py", check=False)
    #import first
    #os.system('python first.py')
    #subprocess.call(" python first.py 1", shell=True)
    os.execv("first.py", sys.argv)
    print("I'm leaving second now")
    break
while thisfile == "first":
    print("this is the first file")
    time.sleep(1)
    #os.system("second.py")
    #exec(open("second.py").read())
    #run("python "+"second.py", check=False)
    #import second
    #os.system('python second.py')
    #subprocess.call(" python second.py 1", shell=True)
    os.execv("second.py", sys.argv)
    print("I'm leaving first now")
    break
time.sleep(1)
sys.exit("Quitting")
```

second.py (basically a copy of first.py)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/bin/bash
#second.py

import time
import os
import sys
from subprocess import run
import subprocess

#thisfile = "first"
thisfile = "second"

time.sleep(3)
while thisfile == "second":
    print("this is the second file")
    time.sleep(1)
    #os.system("first.py")
    #exec(open("first.py").read())
    #run("python "+"first.py", check=False)
    #import first
    #os.system('python first.py')
    #subprocess.call(" python first.py 1", shell=True)
    os.execv("first.py", sys.argv)
    print("I'm leaving second now")
    break
while thisfile == "first":
    print("this is the first file")
    time.sleep(1)
    #os.system("second.py")
    #exec(open("second.py").read())
    #run("python "+"second.py", check=False)
    #import second
    #os.system('python second.py')
    #subprocess.call(" python second.py 1", shell=True)
    os.execv("second.py", sys.argv)
    print("I'm leaving first now")
    break
time.sleep(1)
sys.exit("Quitting")
```

I have tried quite a few solutions as can be seen with my hashed out lines of code.  Nothing so far though has given me the result I am after unfortunately.

EDIT:  This is the part of the actual code i think i am having problems with.  This is the part where I am attempting to publish to my MQTT broker.

```
try:
        client.connect(broker, port, 10) #connect to broker
        time.sleep(1)
except:
        print("Cannot connect")
        sys.exit("Quitting")
```

Instead of exiting with the "quitting" part, will it keep my code alive if i route it to stay within a repeat loop until such time as it successfully connects to the broker again and then continue back with the rest of the script?  Or is this wishful thinking?

Comment: The "in a new terminal" part is a challenge. Is this cross platform or Windows or ??

Comment: This is on a Raspberry Pi.   I'm also still fairly novice with Python, but a keen learner.

Comment: this is an XY question ... you are asking for help with your solution to a problem, instead of asking for help with the problem itself

Comment: We could go into the problem (reason for crashes) instead, but i fear that there will be no resolve there.  I have four scripts running in parallel.  When Virgin Media mess around with my internet connection in some way due to maintenance, 3 out of 4 of my scripts have a tendency to crash because the link to and from the MQTT broker is lost.  My idea was to carry out the solution I'm asking about here rather than trying understand the error which results and trying to code around that.  I'm trying to work out the easiest solution I can with my coding skills being what they are right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. Your `subprocess.call()` option would work - but it depends on the details of implementation. Perhaps the easiest is to use multiprocessing to run the program in a subprocess while the parent simply restarts it as necessary.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def do_the_things(arg1, arg2):
    print("doing the things")
    time.sleep(2) # for test
    raise RuntimeError("Virgin Media dun me wrong")

def launch_and_monitor():
    while True:
        print("start the things")
        proc = mp.Process(target=do_the_things, args=(0, 1))
        proc.start()
        proc.wait()
        print("things went awry")
        time.sleep(2) # a moment before restart hoping badness resolves

if __name__ == "__main__":
    launch_and_monitor()
```

Note: The child process uses the same terminal as the parent. Running separate terminals is quite a bit more difficult. It would depend, for instance, on how you've setup to have a terminal attach to the pi.

If you want to catch and process errors in the parent process, you could write some extra code to catch the error, pickle it, and have a queue to pass it back to the parent. Multiprocessing pools already do that, so you could just have a pool with 1 process and and a single iterable to consume.

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
    while True:
        try:
            result = pool.map(do_the_things, [(0,1)])
        except Exception as e:
            print("caught", e)
```

Comment: hi tdelaney, thanks for your input.  How do you know that a "RuntimeError" is the sort of error I can react to?  Rather than doing what I initially suggested, I'm wondering instead if i can get my code to react more cleverly upon the occurrence of a fault.  Could i do this if I actually knew the type of fault, or does it matter?  I now want to show you where i think my actual code is falling over, but i don't know how to put more code examples up here without starting a whole new thread?

Comment: I've now edited the original post with the area of the code i am actually having an issue with, which if i can fix up to be better, may negate the whole original posts question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it!

For anyone else interested in trying to do what my original question was:

To close down a script on the occurrence of an error and then open either a new script, or a copy of the original one (for the purpose of having the same functionality as the first) in a new terminal window, this is the answer using my original code samples as an example (first.py and second.py where both scripts run the exact same code - other than defining them as different names and this name allocation defined within for which alternate file to open in its place)

first.py

```
import time
import subprocess

thisfile = "first"
#thisfile = "second"

if thisfile == "second":
    restartcommand = 'python3 /home/mypi/myprograms/first.py'
else:
    restartcommand = 'python3 /home/mypi/myprograms/second.py'

time.sleep(3)
while thisfile == "second":
    print("this is the second file")
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.run('lxterminal -e ' + restartcommand, shell=True)
    print("I'm leaving second now")
    break
while thisfile == "first":
    print("this is the first file")
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.run('lxterminal -e ' + restartcommand, shell=True)
    print("I'm leaving first now")
    break
time.sleep(1)
quit()
```

second.py

```
import time
import subprocess

#thisfile = "first"
thisfile = "second"

if thisfile == "second":
    restartcommand = 'python3 /home/mypi/myprograms/first.py'
else:
    restartcommand = 'python3 /home/mypi/myprograms/second.py'

time.sleep(3)
while thisfile == "second":
    print("this is the second file")
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.run('lxterminal -e ' + restartcommand, shell=True)
    print("I'm leaving second now")
    break
while thisfile == "first":
    print("this is the first file")
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.run('lxterminal -e ' + restartcommand, shell=True)
    print("I'm leaving first now")
    break
time.sleep(1)
quit()
```

The result of running either one of these will be that the program runs, then opens the other file and starts running that before closing down itself and this operation will continue back and forth, back and forth until you close down the running file before it gets a chance to open the other file.
Try it!  it's fun!